# RewriteEngine and excluding directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When I use this to force all the requests to go to https, it works fine (even the Redirect 301):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

Redirect 301 /some.htm      https://domain.nl/SEO-friendly-dir/
```

Now, when I try to exclude two directories with two additional lines, it doesn't work anymore (the http is suddenly working again).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/dir1/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/dir2/"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

Redirect 301 /some.htm      https://domain.nl/SEO-friendly-dir/
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `[OR]` had precedence on the implicit AND at the end of `RewriteCond` no1.  So you have no1 AND (no2 or no3).  So your rule will now only be triggered if https is off and you have /dir1/ or /dir2/.  Anything else is not redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below if you are looking for exclusion of urls,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

Redirect 301 /some.htm      https://domain.nl/SEO-friendly-dir/
```